# Add a dropdown list from multi level dynamic collections

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I have these Models.

ProjectViewModel

```
public class ProjectViewModel
    {
        //some properties..

        public IList<ScopeOfWorkViewModel> ScopeOfWork { get; set; }
    }
```

ScopeOfWorkViewModel

```
public class ScopeOfWorkViewModel
    {
        //some properties
        public IList<MaterialsViewModel> Materials { get; set; }
    }
```

MaterialsViewModel

```
 public class MaterialsViewModel
        {
            public int MaterialId { get; set; }
            [Display(Name = "Material")]
            public string MaterialName { get; set; }
            public int? Quantity { get; set; }
            public double? Cost { get; set; }
            public int? ScopeOfWorkId { get; set; }

            // should be a drop down list and get its data from database
            public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> CategoryList { get; set; }
        }
```

Category Model

```
 public partial class tblCategory
    {
        public tblCategory()
        {
            this.tblMaterials = new HashSet<tblMaterial>();
        }

        public int CategoryId { get; set; }
        public string CategoryName { get; set; }

        public virtual ICollection<tblMaterial> tblMaterials { get; set; }
    }
```

This is my View

```
@model MigratingDB.Models.ProjectViewModel
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.js"></script>
@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()

    <div class="form-horizontal" id="ProjectForm">
        <h4>ProjectViewModel</h4>
        <hr />
        @Html.ValidationSummary(true, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })

        Dynamically add ScopeOfWork and Materials<br />
        <a href="javascript:void(0)" id="addScope">Add Scope of Work</a>
        <div id="scopes">
            <div class="scope">
                <div class="materials">
                    <div class="material">
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
                <input type="submit" value="Create" class="btn btn-default" />
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
}

<div>
    @Html.ActionLink("Back to List", "Index")
</div>


<div id="newScope" style="display:none">
    <div class="scope">
        <h3>Scope</h3>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="_#__ScopeOfWorkName" class="control-label col-md-2">Scope Of Work</label>
            <div class="col-md-10">
                <input class="form-control" type="text" id="_#__ScopeOfWorkName" name="ScopeOfWork[#].ScopeOfWorkName" value="">
            </div>
        </div>
        <input type="hidden" class="scopeindex" name="ScopeOfWork.Index" value="#" />

        <div class="materials">
            <h4>Material</h4>
            <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="addmaterial">Add Material</a>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<div id="newMaterial" style="display:none">
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="_#__Materials_%__MaterialName" class="control-label col-md-2">Material</label>
        <div class="col-md-2">
            <input class="form-control" type="text" id="_#__Materials_%__MaterialName" name="ScopeOfWork[#].Materials[%].MaterialName" value="">
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="_#__Materials_%__Quantity" class="control-label col-md-2">Quantity</label>
        <div class="col-md-1">
            <input class="form-control" type="text" id="_#__Materials_%__Quantity" name="ScopeOfWork[#].Materials[%].Quantity" value="">
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="_#__Materials_%__Cost" class="control-label col-md-2">Cost</label>
        <div class="col-md-1">
            <input class="form-control" type="text" id="_#__Materials_%__Cost" name="ScopeOfWork[#].Materials[%].Cost" value="">
        </div>
    </div>

//build a category drop down list here

    <input type="hidden" class="materialindex" name="ScopeOfWork[#].Materials.Index" value="%" />
</div>

<script>
    var form = $('form');
    var scope = $('#newScope');
    var material = $('#newMaterial');

    form.on('click', '.addmaterial', function () {
        var clone = material.clone();
        var scopeIndex = $(this).closest('.scope').find('.scopeindex').val();
        clone.html($(clone).html().replace(/#/g, scopeIndex));

        var materialIndex = new Date().getTime();
        clone.html($(clone).html().replace(/%/g, materialIndex));
        $(this).closest('.materials').append(clone.html());
        form.data('validator', null);
        $.validator.unobtrusive.parse(form);
    });

    $('#addScope').click(function () {
        var clone = scope.clone();
        var scopeIndex = new Date().getTime();
        clone.html($(clone).html().replace(/#/g, scopeIndex));
        $('#scopes').append(clone.html());
        form.data('validator', null);
        $.validator.unobtrusive.parse(form);
    });
</script>
```

Kindly help me build a dropdownlist for the category in each time I create a MaterialViewModel object and post it to my database. I have a category table in which i want to pass its values to generate a dropdownlist. I prefer to use strongly typed model rather than using ViewBag

Comment: Its not clear what your asking. Are you wanting to generate a dropdownlist to select a category for each `MaterialsViewModel`? That model does not even contain a property to bind the selected Category to. And do not use a data model in your view model (you should have a property which is `IEnumerable<SelectListItem>`, not `IEnumerable<tblCategory>`. And edit your code to remove all the irrelevant stuff (we do not want to wade through all that view code for properties that obviously work. Just show what is relevant to your question.

Comment: Updated. Yes, I want to generate a category for each MaterialsViewModel preferably without using ViewBag.

Comment: And what do you want to bind the selected value to?

Comment: I want to post it on my material table on the database. So each material have its own categoryId.

Comment: Then to start, you need a property for  the CategoryId in your `MaterialsViewModel` - say `public int SelectedCategory { get; set; }` You also have other issues here - your not generating the html for existing items so you cant editing existing data or return the view is `ModelState` is invalid. And your not generating any validation attributes for properties of `ScopeOfWorkViewModel` and `MaterialsViewModel` (and if you do not want any validation, its a bit pointless reparsing the `$.validator`)

Comment: I'dd add some validation attributes soon, I just have to finish the view in creating a project. I''ll clarify my question. I want to pass the data from the category table of my database to generate a dropdownlist for the MaterialsViewModel.

Comment: Yes, I know, but a dropdown list needs a property to bind to in addition to the property for the options to be displayed.

Comment: After adding the properties, How should I manipulate the selectlist in the controller?

Comment: About to eat. Give me an hour and I'll add an answer showing how to do this.

Comment: Sure thing, thank you. Having really a hard time in using MVC.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `ProjectViewModel` needs a property `IEnumerable<SelectListItem>` (or an `IEnumerable` of a class containing 2 properties for the options value and text) so that you can pass the option values to the view (in case there are no existing `MaterialsViewModel`). Your `MaterialsViewModel` also needs a property to bind the selected category to.

```
public class ProjectViewModel
{
    // some properties..
    public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> CategoryList { get; set; }
    public IList<ScopeOfWorkViewModel> ScopeOfWork { get; set; }
}
....
public class MaterialsViewModel
{
    public int MaterialId { get; set; }
    ....
    // public int? ScopeOfWorkId { get; set; } this is not required
    public int SelectedCategory { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> CategoryList { get; set; }
}
```

Then in the GET method, initialize your view model and populate the `CategoryList`, for example

```
IEnumerable categories = db.tblCategory; // select all categories
ProjectViewModel model = new ProjectViewModel()
{
    CategoryList = new SelectList(categories, "CategoryId", "CategoryName"),
    .... set other properties as required
};
return View(model);
```

The in the view, include a script to convert the `CategoryList` to a javascript array

```
<script>
    var form = $('form');
    ....
    var categories = @Html.Raw(Json.Encode(Model.CategoryList));

    form.on('click', '.addmaterial', function () {
        ....
```

Then in your template (in the ` element), add the html for the select control (but without any options except for the label option if you want one). Note the additional class name for selection.

```
<div class="form-group">
    <label for="_#__Materials_%__SelectedCategory" class="control-label col-md-2">Cost</label>
    <div class="col-md-1">
        <select class="form-control category" id="_#__Materials_%__SelectedCategory" name="ScopeOfWork[#].Materials[%].SelectedCategory">
            <option value="">Please select a category</option>
        </select>
    </div>
</div>
```

and modify your script to add the options based on the values in the javascript array.

```
form.on('click', '.addmaterial', function () {
    var clone = material.clone();
    ....
    clone.html($(clone).html().replace(/%/g, materialIndex));

    // Add the options
    var select = clone.find('.category');
    $.each(categories, function(index, item) {
        select.append($('<option></option>').val(item.Value).text(item.Text));
    });

    $(this).closest('.materials').append(clone.html());
    form.data('validator', null);
    $.validator.unobtrusive.parse(form);
});
```

Note that your not rendering any html for existing items so if anything is invalid and you return the view, all the data the user dynamically added will be lost - you need nested `for` loops that. And your not rendering the html for validation on the dynamically added elements.

Comment: What do you mean by not rendering html? I referred to the last example you've given to me. I saw for loops in each <div> append by the javascript but I didn't understand it at all. Do you mean that I need the html helpers to render the necessary elements needed for the validation so once the view is returned the data added by the user will not be lost?

Comment: That is the subject of a separate question, but essentially you need `@for(int i - 0; i < Model.ScopeOfWork.Count; i++) { // generate form controls for each ScopeOfWork @for(int j = 0; j < Model.ScopeOfWork[i].Materials .Count; j++) { // generate controls for each Material within each ScopeOfWork }}`

Comment: Even if you have no initial `ScopeOfWork` items, it is necessary so that if you return the view, the data the the user has added will be rendered (otherwise it will be lost)

Comment: Now it worked! I don't quite get on some points of what you've said but eventually i'll fully understand it. Thank you for the answer. I'll study the code you've shown.

Comment: I tried to put a for loop in the view just like you've said but it has an error `Object reference not set to an instance of an object` `@for (int i = 0; i < Model.ScopeOfWork.Count; i++)`. Do i have to pass in the GET method a temporary data?

Comment: Just initialize your model with `model.ScopeOfWork = new List<ScopeOfWorkViewModel>` (or initialize the collections in a parameterless constructor for each view model).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/146643/discussion-between-stephen-muecke-and-progammer101).